# SimpleDateFormat parsing results are odd

Tags: java, date

I want to parse dates from a filesystem and get them in this format:

```
2013-07-29 14:49:53.813588954 +0200
```

Therefore my pattern looks like this

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS Z
```

And finally my code:

```
String rawDate = "2013-07-29 14:49:53.813588954 +0200";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS Z");
Date date = sdf.parse(rawDate);

SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
String parsedDate = out.format(date);

System.out.println(rawDate + " -> " + parsedDate);
```

But my output looks like this:

```
2013-07-29 14:49:53.813588954 +0200 -> 2013-08-08 00:49:41.000000954 +0200
```

I even tried with `setLenient(false)` but then I got a ParseException.

Comment: I executed your code. I am getting output : 2013-07-29 14:49:53.813588954 +0200 -> 2013-08-08 04:19 (I think this is expected.)

Comment: Are you sure about the output? Your code on ideone: https://ideone.com/uOehey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've parsed 813588954 as a number of milliseconds - that's over 9 days, and it's being added to 2013-07-29 14:49:53.

Basically, `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't handle parsing nanoseconds, and `java.util.Date` only supports millisecond precision anyway.

If you can *possibly* use Java 8, I'd recommend using `java.time` for everything - don't use `java.util.Date` at all. If you can use `java.time` for parsing but have to use `java.util.Date` for the rest, that will at least help.

If you can't use Java 8 at all, I'd suggest manually modifying the string to truncate the nanoseconds to milliseconds and then parse with `SimpleDateFormat` using a pattern that uses `.SSS`.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing nanoseconds is supported by Java 8's DateTimeFormatter. For this you need to update your pattern:

```
String rawDate = "2013-07-29 14:49:53.813588954 +0200";
DateTimeFormatter rawDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnnnnnnnn Z");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(rawDate, rawDateFormatter);
System.out.println(zonedDateTime); // prints 2013-07-29T14:49:53.813588954+02:00

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.format(formatter)); // prints 2013-07-29 14:49
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `53.813588954` means 53 seconds and 813588954 milliseconds and 813588954 milliseconds is around 9 days. When doing the formatting on your second output (i.e. `parsedDate`), Java automatically rounded up by the sequence of seconds -> minutes -> hours -> days -> months -> years.